# $ \int e^{-\sin t} \cos t~ dt - \int e^{-\sin t} \cos t \sin t~ dt $

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$  \int e^{-\sin t} \cos t~ dt - \int e^{-\sin t} \cos t \sin t~ dt $

According to the answer,

It substituted $x=\sin t$

$ \int e^{-x}~ dx- \int e^{-x}(x)~ dx $

Why did the answer remove $\cos t$ ?

Comment: SImply because $dx=\cos(t)\,dt$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici is there a way to prove this ?

Comment: It is $\int e^{-\sin t} \cos t dt - \int e^{-\sin t} \cos t \sin t dt=\int e^{-\sin t} d\sin t - \int e^{-\sin t} \sin t d \sin t$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I=\int e^{-\sin t} \cos t dt - \int e^{-\sin t} \cos t \sin t dt$$

You are substituting $x=\sin t$ 
Differentiate both sides w.r.t $t$

Thus $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\cos t$$
$${dx}=\cos(t)  {dt}$$
Thus $$I=\int e^{-\sin t} \cdot dx - \int e^{-\sin t}  \sin t \cdot dx$$
$$I=\int e^{-x} \cdot dx - \int e^{-x} \cdot  x \cdot dx$$

Answer (score 2):

[\begin{array}{l}\int {{e^{ - \sin t}}} \cos tdt - \int {{e^{ - \sin t}}} \sin t\cos tdt\\There\,are\,two\,parts\,of\,this\,question.\\Use\,the\,formula\int {{U^n}} du = \frac{{{u^{n + 1}}}}{{n + 1}} + c\,to\,solve\,the\,\sec ond\,part.\\You\,donot\,need\,to\,solve\,the\,first\,part\,it\,will\,cancel\,when\,you\,{\mathop{\rm int}} egrate\,the\,\sec ond\,part.\end{array}]

Comment: Hello Cipher, welcome to MathStackExchange! I have edited your post to included the mathjax syntax we use here. Please take a look and familiarise yourself with the usage of the typesetting language, and also check my edits to make sure I did not make a mistake in your intentions!

Comment: Thanks, it is perfect.